# CSS: how to apply different animation to same elements?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, cubic-bezier

I have water animation. I want two `keyframes` to have `cubic-bezier(1,.41,.74,.45)` and third one to have `cubic-bezier(.38,.8,.68,.09)`. In other words, I need waves to loop first 2 times same way, and on last one to behave differently. Overall, there are 3 `keyframe` loops in animation. Is there a way to specify different `cubic-bezier`s for different keyframes or apply different animations for same elements?

Pure `CSS`. No additional elements.

This is example for the [first part of animation](https://jsfiddle.net/fbpf3oz4/) and this is for the [second part](https://jsfiddle.net/2bzLfb2p/).

Comment: They both look same to me

Comment: second one stops more in the middle

Comment: if you want in one animation, you need to control it with the % in your keyframes

Comment: tried controlling with %, but because cubic-bezier is being applied to each frame, it looked very weird and edgy. Animation was no longer smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your requirement.

But about your question

> Is there a way to specify different cubic-beziers for different keyframes

Yes, it's possible

```css
@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.38,.8,.68,.09);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.27);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, .41, .74, .45);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.wave {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 4px red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: ripple 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```